# An anagrammed logic puzzle!

Tags: logical-deduction, cipher, anagram

ot rleow utbrctsa aacpilt hwti
dioiatdn het ryuo
s-bcBPEFfJDfeFmksmPOkChDhrgBqjD-i---ffeNB

Comment: Would you please be able to give a hint? I feel like it might be confusing to some people how to decode the third line.

Comment: it's a riddle + logic puzzle, you've figured out a hint already, work on it!

Comment: I agree, but here's the thing: How are we supposed to structure the final answer? It honestly doesn't make sense due to there being, once again, no sense.

Comment: The answer is in the form of a phrase/sentence

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

---

The first sentence:

> ot rleow utbrctsa aacpilt hwti

> to lower subtract capital with

For that, I just realized that each word was an anagram of another word, however, looking at the formatting of the sentence, it seems that I might need to rearrange the order later on.

The second sentece:

> dioiatdn het ryuo

> addition the your

Easy! Now the third sentence shouldn't be *that* difficult right?

> s-bcBPEFfJDfeFmksmPOkChDhrgBqjD-i---ffeNB

Oh. Well, I'll try putting together the (partial) sentence for at least a partial answer here. I won't be able to solve this completely right now, but this is honestly as far as I can go right now. The partial sentence that I have put together so far is

> to subtract the capital ... with ... your ... addition

Note that the ellipses represent that there is something that goes there that  I haven't decoded yet, and note that the last two words ("your" and "addition") I don't even know where those will go yet.